# Eliminate starting characters from full path name of directory in PHP

Tags: php, directory

```
$destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

I am using the above to get the full path till the folder containing the above script. I want to eliminate starting portion of the string to get only the current folder name.

Eg: if **$destination_path = E:/www/stack;**  I want to eliminate **E:/www/** from it to get only *stack* as result.

Comment: Following what logic - do you want to always go up one level?

Comment: I just need the directory name in which the script is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$folder = basename($destination_path);
```

`getcwd` will give the `current working directory`, which would be the directory of the php file called for execution or the `current working directory` in case you are executing from the command line.

If you want to get the directory which contains the file with this specific code, use

```
$destination_path = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$folder = basename($destination_path);
```